# Dynamically build a Unirest post request in Python

Tags: python, post, dictionary, unirest

I'm writing a method to an API. The Unirest post call is of the form

```
response = unirest.post("http://some.url.org/arg",
                       {
                          "X-Mashape-Authorization": "authCode"
                       },
                       {
                          "key1": "val1",
                          "key2": "val2",
                          "key3": "val3",
                          "key4": "val4"
                       }
                       );
```

key1 is mandatory, while key2, key3, and key4 are optional. I want to have one method called

```
update(v1, v2, v3, v4)
```

which will create the params dictionary, add it to the POST, then send it out. The first part, I've got down. While writing it, I got the nagging feeling that dictionaries aren't sorted. One quick test, and it proved I was right. Since it's an API, I'm fairly sure they require the fields to be in the right order. Is there any way I can insert the parameters into the dictionary in the correct order? I can't use an OrderedDict, as it's a non-hashable type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to worry about sorting for an API.  You are passing a key-value object so the api should be accessing you passed args with a dict["key1"] or its equivalent for a hash map.